# Is there a word or phrase for someone who is repeatedly told NOT to do something, does it anyway, and gets hostile when it's mentioned?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone who is repeatedly told NOT to do something, does it anyway, and gets hostile when it's mentioned?

Someone who repeats behavior after being told not to nicely >6 times, gets called out and reacts as if the person requesting the change is being cruel or abusive. (Victimizes self to deflect blame for their own behavior).

Comment: Oppositional? Contrary? The Terrible Twos? Entitled? Antisocial? No I'm not...where does it say so?

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence as required per the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. " Also, you need to provide more context.

Comment: This is what's commonly called a "turd".

Comment: There are many threads coming up with synonyms for 'obdurate', 'stubborn' etc, which only answer the 'refuse to stop' part. The duplicate addresses the 'attack the person trying to get the person to change behaviour'; the accepted answer is '**recrimination**'.

Answer (score 2):

"recalcitrant" may fit the bill though it does not convey the "casting oneself in the role of a victim" aspect.

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recalcitrant)

> - If you describe someone or something as recalcitrant, you mean that they are unwilling to obey orders or are difficult to deal with.

From [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recalcitrant)

> - Stubbornly resistant to or defiant of authority or guidance.  A person who is recalcitrant rebels against authority.

Answer (score 1):

How about **brat**? From M-W:

> **[brat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brat)**: an ill-mannered annoying child; an ill-mannered immature person

A **brat** could be a child or an adult -- it's age neutral. And one knows one when one sees one. N.B.: Wow! Four uses of *one* in a one *sho*rt sentence!

Answer (score 0):

Stubborn could fit, it really depends on the context, it does not exactly convey the "hostile when its mentioned" part.

Here is the definition:

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stubborn)

- Someone who is stubborn or who behaves in a stubborn way is determined to do       what they want and is very unwilling to change their mind.

From Oxford

- having or showing dogged determination not to change one's attitude or position on something, especially in spite of good arguments or reasons to do so.

Perhaps to include "hostile when it's mentioned" part you could add another word to it, e.g. *"His Aggressive Stubborness"*

Hope that helps